# Get file system type with action script

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I wonder if you could help me finding way to get "file System Type" (such as FAT, NTFS or cdfs, etc..) that flash projector file or SWF is running from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it only if you are using AIR app. The functionality was introduced with AIR 2.0 and you can get more details by [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/html/dev/WS86fc450a3af174de-70f653dd1220e161719-8000.html).

```
var volumes = air.StorageVolumeInfo.storageVolumeInfo.getStorageVolumes(); 
for (i = 0; i < volumes.length; i++) 
{ 
    air.trace(volumes[i].name, volumes[i].fileSystemType); 
}
```

Otherwise it is forbidden due to security policies.